# Jest fails to transpile import from npm linked module

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs, lerna

I have a project with multiple modules (using [Lerna](http://lernajs.io)) and I want to use Jest to run tests. However, when I test code that uses a shared module (npm linked module via Lerna) it seems that Babel is not correctly applied and I get the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

The structure of my project is like this:

```
- my-project
|- shared
|- native
|- web
```

`web` and `native` require the `shared` module. When I go into the `shared` directory and run the local tests in Jest everything works fine. If I run Jest tests in the `web` directory the above error occurs as soon as I include something from `shared`.

Here is a super simple test that causes the error:

```
import { util } from 'shared';

it('returns false if not prod', () => {
    expect(util.isProd()).toBe(false);
});
```

My `.babelrc` looks like this:

```
{
    "presets": [
        "env",
        "flow",
        "react"
        ],
    "plugins": [
        "flow-react-proptypes",
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        "transform-class-properties"
    ]
}
```

I tried everything I could find, including:

- Different Babel configs, including one with the `es2015` preset and enabling `modules` for the test environment
- Manually setting the `transform` option for babel-jest
- As mentioned, Jest can be executed in the `shared` module, thus, Jest and `babel-jest` are installed there as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had to change the `transformIgnorePatterns` configuration option of Jest in the `package.json` of the `web` module.

```
{
    "jest": {
        "transformIgnorePatterns": [
            "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!shared|another)"
        ]
    },
}
```