# Jest Is Not Transpiling ES6 Modules In Test (SyntaxError: Unexpected token export)

Tags: jestjs, es6-modules, babel-jest

I'm at a boiling point with getting Jest to understand ES6 modules import/export syntax and it is hindering my project development progress. My project structure is the following:

```
root module
  org-domain (ES6)
  org-services (ES6)
  react-ui-module (React via CRA2)
```

`org-services` has a local path dependency on `org-domain` in its package json:

```
// in org-services package.json

"dependencies": {
   "@org/domain": "file:../org-domain",
},
```

My `.babelrc` in `org-services` is the following:

```
{
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-flow", "@babel/preset-env"]
      "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"]
    }
  },
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-flow",
    ["@babel/preset-env", {
      "targets": {
        "esmodules": true
      }
    }]
  ],
  "plugins": [
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./node_modules/@org/domain"],
      "alias": {
        "@org/constants": "./node_modules/@org/domain/src/constants",
        "@org/contracts": "./node_modules/@org/domain/src/request-contracts"
      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

I do not know if the problem is due to how I am including my dependencies so I'm going to add the finer details of anything related to my import/export of these modules for the sake of clarity.

In the implementation files of `org-services` I am importing `org-domain` using npm scoped syntax like so: `import ... from '@org/domain`

Here are some observations I have:

In local development, when I try to reference click `@org/domain`, instead of being directed to `org-services/node_modules/@org/domain` I get redirected to the actual relative directory location which is `root/org-services`. I believe Jest ignores `node_modules` (correct me if I am wrong) but in my `jest.config.js` for `org-services`, I have:

```
collectCoverage: true,
coverageDirectory: 'coverage',
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
  '/node_modules/'
],
moduleDirectories: [
  'src',
  'node_modules'
],
moduleFileExtensions: [
  'js'
],
transform: {
  '^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'
},
transformIgnorePatterns: [
  'node_modules/(?!@org/domain)$'
]
```

To my understanding, everything should just work right now with all the configuration I have with respect to setting the plugin `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` in test (within `.babelrc`) and including the `'^.+\\.js$': 'babel-jest'` instruction under the `transform` key in `jest.config.js` located under `org-services` -- but it does not.

I have tried every single thing I could find online with respect to this issue with no success. I have not gotten anywhere since and my patience is lost with this testing framework and the lack of support for ES6. It should not be this hard, so clearly I am doing something wrong here. Please advise.

### Update 1

Found another SO post that is a mirror of this situation I am in.
[Jest fails to transpile import from npm linked module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44413678/jest-fails-to-transpile-import-from-npm-linked-module)

Unfortunately, the provided solution does not work for my case.

Comment: Have you made any progress with this?

Comment: @42tg I was not able to solve this problem. In the end and in complete frustration, I had to merge my separate org-module packaged project into a single, monolithic package. The fact that a Yarn-workspace esque, multi-package project setup is not supported out of the box is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading from @babel/xyz: 7.0.0 to 7.1.2 I started getting an error regarding "import"

```
Jest encountered an unexpected token

<snip>

Details:

C:\....\SstcStrategy.test.js:2
import sequelizeFixtures from 'sequelize-fixtures';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:403:17)
```

To fix this I had to add `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` as you mention in your question.

My `babel.config.js` now looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    [
      '@babel/preset-env',
      {
        targets: {
          node: '8.10',
        },
        debug: false,
      },
    ],
  ],
  ignore: ['node_modules'],
  plugins: [
    '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
    '@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs',

    // Stage 2
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', { legacy: true }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator',
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions',

    // Stage 3
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import',
    '@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta',
    ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', { loose: false }],
    '@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings',
  ],
};
```

Also BTW you don't need to define `babel-jest` transform in `jest.config.js` as this is the default setting.

Hope this helps